# How to set types for absolute path and relative path?

Tags: typescript, types, relative-path, deno, absolute-path

I need to deal with absolute path variables and relative path variables in Deno TypeScript. The [`std`](https://deno.land/std) library has the [`ParsedPath`](https://deno.land/std/path/_interface.ts?source=) type, but that's not specific enough. Besides adding the `absolute`/`relative` word in the variable name, is there a way to type it as well? At best it should work in both Windows and Linux, but if it's hard then Windows is suffice.

Comment: You might be able to do something with template literal types or alternatively with branded types (the latter will require a type predicate or assertion). What's your definition of a relative path? For instance, is `"example"` a relative path? Or do you just mean things like `./x` and `../x` and `../../x`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could subclass `ParsedPath` and add a member saying whether it's absolute or relative, although looking at the type it seems to be for absolute paths.

Comment: Hmm, I realize that I mostly use `x/y` format more than `./x/y`, so if I can be greedy then it's great. Can you give an example of the subclass of `ParsedPath`?

Comment: jsejcksn's done so below. I shouldn't have said *subclass*, specifically. "Create a subtype" is more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some observations:

- The properties of the [`ParsedPath`](https://deno.land/std@0.219.1/path/_interface.ts?source#L7) interface are mutable, so whatever type you derive from it must enforce that instances cannot be mutated (e.g. by using the utility [`Readonly<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype)) — otherwise, a consumer might make changes to it, which would circumvent the type system discrimination that you seek.
- The string property [`root`](https://deno.land/std@0.219.1/path/_interface.ts?source#L11) will be the empty string `""` for relative parsed paths — which can be used to discriminate whether the path is relative or absolute.

Here is an example:

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#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-KtwMRQPWHlxW6Kbdd49uWGUQBex0iHdYym+P2AL8ViAA)

```ts
import { parse } from "https://deno.land/std@0.219.1/path/parse.ts";
import type { ParsedPath } from "https://deno.land/std@0.219.1/path/_interface.ts";

type AbsoluteParsedPath = Readonly<ParsedPath> & { readonly isAbsolute: true };
type RelativeParsedPath = Readonly<ParsedPath> & { readonly isAbsolute: false };

function parsePath(path: string): AbsoluteParsedPath | RelativeParsedPath {
  const parsed = parse(path);
  return Object.assign(parsed, { isAbsolute: parsed.root.length > 0 });
}

declare const inputPath: string;

const parsed = parsePath(inputPath);
//    ^? const parsed: AbsoluteParsedPath | RelativeParsedPath

if (parsed.isAbsolute) {
  parsed
  //^? const parsed: AbsoluteParsedPath
} else {
  parsed
  //^? const parsed: RelativeParsedPath
}
```

Comment: To be fair, for the `isAbsolute`, I think it's only `root` that needs to be read-only. But I'm with you, the whole thing should be (just in `ParsedPath` itself), otherwise you can assign to `base` without updating `name` and `ext`.

Comment: occasionally I need to keep the path in `string` type, not `ParsedPath` interface. For example when inputting to [`Deno.readDir()`](https://deno.land/api?s=Deno.readDir "Deno.readDir | Runtime APIs | Deno"). Is there a way to have something like `type AbsoluteStringPath = format(AbsoluteParsedPath)`? ([`format()`](https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts?s=format "format | /path/mod.ts | std@0.219.1 | Deno") generates full string path from `Partial<ParsedPath>`)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78155036/how-to-set-types-for-absolute-path-and-relative-path/78158062?noredirect=1#comment137793228_78158062) @Ooker You can use the function [`isAbsolute`](https://deno.land/std@0.220.0/path/is_absolute.ts) with a string path to make a determination for a string.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78155036/438273#comment137800771_78158062) And, as [already mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78155036/438273#comment137784613_78155036), [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) [branded](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+branded+string) strings is the conventional approach for discriminating them when [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#handbook-content) don't apply.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78155036/how-to-set-types-for-absolute-path-and-relative-path/78158062?noredirect=1#comment137791480_78158062) @T.J.Crowder Yes, I think the relationship of those properties was not considered well-enough in the design of the structure. They should be codependent and recomputed when one is mutated.